# Flutter - Why Material elevation not working?

Tags: flutter

Material elevation in Column not working.

On this code elevation not working.

```dart
    Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Material(
            elevation: 8,
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              color: Colors.yellowAccent,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.white,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

But just remove Container is working. why?

```dart
    Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Material(
            elevation: 8,
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              color: Colors.yellowAccent,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

has next Container.
[image: not working]

remove next Container.
[image: working]

Include SingleChildScrollView and some content message.
It looks like a little shadow appears in the background, but not in the content.

update simple code:

```dart
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Test'),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Material(
            elevation: 8,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 50,
              color: Colors.yellowAccent,
              child: const Text('Some title message'),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    height: 100,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    // Divider
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                    child: const Text('Some content'),
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ))
        ],
      ),
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Try to give space/margin between material and container.

Comment: I think the shadow of the material was covered by container.

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak In my case, Container Include SingleChildScrollView. So can't not add space or margin between material and container. Orz

Comment: Can you share your actual code?

Comment: Ok, update new simple code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `Stack` instead of `Column` if you want the shadow of `Material` was visible even if you scroll the list. And add transparent `Container` on the top of the list.

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Test'),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      // Use stack instead of column
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
          children: [
          // Add transparent container
            Container(
             alignment: Alignment.center,
             height: 60,
             color: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.white,
                // Divider
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                child: const Text('Some content'),
              ),
          ],
            ),
          ),
          Material(
            elevation: 8,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 50,
              color: Colors.yellowAccent,
              child: const Text('Some title message'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found 1 solution, use Ink and set color with decoration instead of using the container and it won't cover the shadow.

ex:
change:

```
Container(
  color: Colors.amber,
)
```

to:

```
Ink(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.amber,
  ),
)
```

result:

Container:

[image: 1]

Ink:

[image: 2]